# How do I sign additional contents in an macOS Automator workflow application?

Tags: macos, automator

I have created an Automator workflow, but want to add extra contents to the resulting app's Contents folder.  If I then edit the workflow and save it again, it fails:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. A code signing error occurred.

/Applications/MyAutomation.app.sb-fa47726f-7pvl6a: Permission denied
In subcomponent: /Applications/MyAutomation.app.sb-fa47726f-7pvl6a/Contents/myshellscript.sh
```

If I force save it (through *Export...*), it overwrites the additional content.

Is it possible to sign the extra contents together with the workflow, or drop code signing for the app?

Comment: You should be able to just manually re-sign it after adding the extra contents - note that everything needs to be in the `Contents` folder.

Comment: @red_menace Thanks! How would I do that?

Comment: From the **Terminal**, it would be something like `/usr/bin/codesign --force --deep --sign your_signing_identity /path/to/app` (don’t forget to quote or escape strings for spaces, etc).